# How to setup a LOCAL STS Service with VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a project were I need to use WIF and STS Service to log in. I need to setup a local STS Service for my tests, but I cannot find how with VS 2015. All I see on the Interwebs is with VS 2012 and 2013. And it does not apply to VS 2015.

The project has already been started and I cannot restart it, a lot of work has been done on it.

Thanks,
Michel

Comment: You will need to explain *how* or *why* the explanations for VS2012/2013 don't work for you. What *is* your problem?

Comment: I think that the explanations for VS2012 and 2013 did not work, as the OP has VS 2015, and tons of available related documentation now obsolete.